# Signing git commits on macOS keeps asking for passphrase

Tags: git, signing, gpg-agent

I've set up Git commit signing on two other Macs in the past, I'm trying to set it up on a new one and failing for reasons that I don't understand. All machines are running High Sierra 10.13.6 (17G65)

1) Installed packages via Homebrew

```
brew install gnupg gpg-agent pinentry-mac gpg1
```

In `~/.gnupg/gpg.conf` I have a keyserver defined, and

```
use-agent
```

In `~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf`

```
pinentry-program /usr/local/bin/pinentry-mac
```

2) Added my private key (it shows up correctly running `gpg -K`)

3) If I run `gpg`, for example with `echo "test" | gpg --clearsign`, I see the pinentry prompt, with a checkbox to store the passphrase in Keychain. At that point, running the same command again won't ask for a password again.

If I try to sign a commit, I don't get the pinentry prompt, but a prompt in the terminal (*you need to provide a passphrase to unlock, etc.*). I can enter my password and signing works, but I need to enter the passphrase every single time.

I've tried uninstalling the packages and starting from scratch multiple times, but no luck.

Answer (score 4):

After at least three hours fighting with this, I realized that Git wasn't using `gpg` (which I was testing with `echo`), but `gpg1`. `echo "test" | gpg1 --clearsign` was behaving like `git commit -S`.

Had to change my `.gitconfig` a while ago when it broke after an [Homebrew update](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/issues/708)

```
[gpg]
     program = /usr/local/bin/gpg1
```

For some reason this config works on older Macs, but not on the new one. Removed this line, signing works as expected using `gpg`, and no requests for password.

Also uninstalled gpg1 at this point

```
brew uninstall gpg1
```